# Link back to user's parent-site profile in Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, users, profile-page

Since there's no "accounts" tab on SE 2.0 Meta pages, there's no link to the user's parent-site profile on the user's Meta profile page.

Please add a link somewhere so I don't develop callouses having to click "visit parent" / "users" / type username / click username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I see what you mean.

I added a link just under the user picture on the left titled "parent user". Not sure if that's the right place or text, exactly.

Comment: @jscott - are you fishing for the Editor badge by any chance :P

Comment: Well that *also*, of course. I couldn't find anything on the right side of the user profile page with a parent link. It's a really slow Sunday here.